# How to fix @nest-modules/mailer service injection?

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to use @nest-modules/mailer. I create a module "example.module.ts" and service "example.service.ts". I load mailer module in app.module.ts as on the documentation. When I inject it in ExampleService, nest throw this error:

```
[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ExampleService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the ExampleModule context.
```

In @nest-modules/mailer docs, load mailer in App.module.ts allow us to inject it everywhere in the entire app.
Am i missing something?

App.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { HandlebarsAdapter, MailerModule } from '@nest-modules/mailer';
import { ExampleModule } from './example/example.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        transport: 'smtps://user@domain.com:pass@smtp.domain.com',
        defaults: {
          from:'"nest-modules" <modules@nestjs.com>',
        },
        template: {
          dir: __dirname + '/templates',
          adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(), // or new PugAdapter()
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
      }),
    }),
    ExampleModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Example.module.ts

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailerService } from '@nest-modules/mailer';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  constructor(private readonly _mailerService: MailerService) {}
}
```

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "tp-nest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "prestart:prod": "rimraf dist && npm run build && cp -r views public dist/",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/src/main.js",
    "start:pm2": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start dist/src/main.js",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nest-modules/mailer": "^1.0.4",
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^3.0.2",
    "automapper-ts": "^1.9.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.0.1",
    "email-check": "^1.1.0",
    "email-existence": "^0.1.6",
    "email-verify": "^0.2.1",
    "handlebars-static": "^2.0.2",
    "hbs": "^4.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "legit": "^1.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mailchecker": "^3.2.26",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.20",
    "nodemailer-html-to-text": "^3.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "server-accepts-email": "^1.11.1",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.0.2",
    "typegoose": "^5.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.9",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/config": "^0.0.34",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.123",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.3.24",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.7",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "supertest": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.7.0",
    "tslint": "5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a ExampleService module First.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EmailService } from './emailService';

@Module({
    providers: [EmailService],
    exports: [EmailService]
})
export class EmailModule {}
```

And finally, register your module inside the AppModule.

```
@Module({
   imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
        useFactory: () => ({
          transport: { host: 'smtp.mailtrap.io', port:  Number(process.env.EMAIL_PORT),
           auth: { user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME, pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD }},
          defaults: {
            from:'"nest-modules" <modules@nestjs.com>',
          },
          template: {
            dir: __dirname + '/templates',
            adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(), // or new PugAdapter()
            options: {
              strict: true,
            },
          },
        }),
      }),
    EmailModule,
   
   ],
...
})
```

Answer (score -3):

You need update the @nestjs/core package additionally the services are different from the modules and if you are going to create a service you must put it in the providers not in the import